# Best way to show spinner/loading while retrieving data in Android, Lollipop+

Tags: android, spinner, loading

So I'm looking for the best way to show a spinner/loading screen while my data is being fetched.
 
 I know there have been a ton of questions, but the questions/answers have been submitted 2+ years ago.

I'm looking for something more current and more agreeable to Google's best practices.

Comment: Why do you think that answers you have found are outdated? Anyway, this is primary opinion based question and not suited for SO.

Comment: They methods/answers all work perfectly.  My concerns are just watching i/o conference videos on best ux practices.  Primary example being, not showing a dialog that says 'loading' vs. just showing a spinner.  Maybe i'm just being a little too peculiar for no reason right now.... :/ .  Thought it would be decent question to ask since ux best practices can change.

Comment: Question like yours are more suitable for [G+ Android Developers](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/117652301242323324573)

Comment: Good point, i'll edit it accordingly.

Comment: i dont know why someone marked this question down? i want to know the same thing. been trying to use progressdialog to no avail and from some comments ive read on here your not meant to use it?

Answer (score 2):

[SwipeRefreshLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html) is pretty modern an pretty popular too. I use it a lot. [Here](http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/swipe-to-refresh.html#swipe-to-refresh-swipe-to-refresh) is the desing pattern and some video animations showing you what it will look like. [Here](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/implementing-swipe-to-refresh/) is some basic example how to implement it, it's pretty simple too.

Comment: Looks pretty cool, thanks for the resources!  Going to implement and then return and respond.  Thanks again Bojan!

Answer (score 1):

Consider this approach:

- Use Events - this decouples your application code and here is how you can achieve what you want:
- If you use a library like EventBus, you simply create an Event class with a variable called loadingCompleted - you can then set its value when the loading is completed to true.
- Now, the way EventBus works is that you can register to listen to events in your activity or fragment then override onEvent(YourEventClass event) method.
- Once your loading is finished, you can notify the activity or fragment by doing a post - again, EventBus documentation shows how to easily do this.
- Inside onEvent() method in the subscribing class, you simply dismiss the progress dialog as long as loadingCompleted is set to true.
- Another idea to avoid showing the progress dialog all the times even when there is no new data to load is perhaps set a variable in your activity to check if you need to load the data or not.

You can find the library and how to use it [here](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/blob/master/HOWTO.md)

I hope this gives you an idea. Good luck.